# Handlebars not parsing data

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, templating

I am trying to use handlebars to parse a javascript object but for some reason Handlebars is not loading the data properly...

Here is my template file:

```
{{> header}}
<h1>Handlebars JS Example</h1>
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
<table>
    <thead> 
        <th>Name</th> 
        <th>Job Title</th> 
        <th>Twitter</th> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        {{#users}} 
        <tr> 
            <td>{{fullName person}}</td> 
            <td>{{jobTitle}}</td> 
            <td><a href="https://twitter.com/{{twitter}}">@{{twitter}}</a></td> 
        </tr> 
        {{/users}} 
    </tbody> 
</table> 
</script>
    <body>
    <!-- Insertion point for handlebars template -->
        <div id="main" style="margin-left:100px">
        </div>
    </body> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/templating.js"></script>
```

Here is my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var source = $("#some-template").html(); 
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

    var data = { 
        users: [ { 
            person: {
                firstName: "Garry", 
                lastName: "Finch"
            },
            jobTitle: "Front End Technical Lead",
            twitter: "gazraa" 
        }, {
            person: {
                firstName: "Garrasd", 
                lastName: "Finch"
            }, 
            jobTitle: "Photographer",
            twitter: "photobasics"
        }, {
            person: {
                firstName: "Garry", 
                lastName: "Finch"
            }, 
            jobTitle: "LEGO Geek",
            twitter: "minifigures"
        } ]
    }; 

    Handlebars.registerHelper('fullName', function(person) {
      return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
    });

    console.log(template(data));

    $("#main").append(template(data));

});
```

Note - when I console.log(template(data)), I get the following:

```
<table>
<thead> 
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Job Title</th> 
    <th>Twitter</th> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
</tbody>
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?? I'm using node.js + express.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define any block helper for `users` but trying to use it in the template.

Change these lines

```
...
{{#users}} 
...
{{/users}}
...
```

to these:

```
...
{{#each users}}
...
{{/each}}
...
```

Check out the documentation here: http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration

> **The each block helper**
>
> You can iterate over a list using the built-in each helper. Inside the
>   block, you can use this to reference the element being iterated over.

Comment: Hi - I tried that, but no luck. Note - the example above is based on this:

http://jsfiddle.net/aybalasubramanian/N2b5M/1/